# Can't run 3D Analyst extension in custom script tool

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, 3d-analyst, python-script-tool

I have custom python script in which I use 3D Analyst function "Add surface information", it works fine when I run the script through ArcCatalog Python Console, but when I try to run the script as Script Tool ArcGIS crashes without any reasonable error (program just exits). I continued to explore this problem further and concluded that I can't run any of 3D Analyst functions via script tool, but I can run them in python console.
For example:

```py
import arcpy
#Get inputs from tool
lasdataset = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
footprints = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
#Calculate Z_MAX
arcpy.ddd.LasPointStatsByArea(lasdataset,footprints, "Z_MAX")
```

Basically ArcGIS crashes when I run this simple script with my custom tool, but completes it fine when I run it in Python console with the same input data and hard-coded paths.

- I have the 3D Analyst extension and it's enabled;
- I encountered this issue on my ArcGIS 10.3.1. with Advanced license
- I tried to run different functions with my tool and it never crashed. It crashed only with 3D Analyst functions.

What could be the problem?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1.

Comment: Best to use and error handler to give you feedback on why and where your code is crashing.  See this link https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/python/error-handling-with-python.htm.  Add the error handler, run your code, then post the error.  Also, it may be necessary for you to check out the 3D Analyst extension in your code. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/checkoutextension.htm

Comment: Even though you *have* 3d analyst extension enabled (check with arcpy.CheckExtension('3d') https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q30000007n000000) you need to *check it out* with arcpy.CheckOutExtension('3d') to make sure python knows you've got that extension... it's also good to return it with arcpy.CheckInExtension('3d') at the end of your code and any cases where sys.exit() is called. This is also the case with any other extension. The script runs from python console because that is in direct communication with ArcGIS in a way that a script is not.

Comment: Thanks GBG and Michael for your replies, but unfortunately none of your tips helped. Error handlers didn't work, because program just exits with default Send/Don't send error report window. I added CheckOutExtension('3d') function, but it also didn't help. My script executes even through CMD, but  crashes with script tool.

Comment: Oh, that is a different problem. I would suggest starting with disabling background geoprocessing http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/64bit-background.htm which is known to be somewhat buggy, if that doesn't work see if you have multiple python installs, this can also cause problems with scripts. Next try reinstalling ArcGIS, if it still doesn't work it's time to contact Esri support.

Comment: 3D Analyst enabled in BOTH catalog and ArcMap?